# Drupal 7 uuid.module Database update 7103 fails

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I finished upgrading a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7. All fields have been migrated. When I run update now I get this UUID error

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: http://drupal220/update.php?

op=selection&token=bLDFFBM8NZi09U0is5p6eim_do1vePHV5iNjLWLu8u4&id=10&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal220\sites\all\modules\uuid\uuid.install on line 266
```

The update process was aborted prematurely while running update #7103 in uuid.module. All errors have been logged. You may need to check the watchdog database table

manually.

Watchdog report

```
Location http://drupal220/update.php?op=selection&token=bLDFFBM8NZi09U0is5p6eim_do1vePHV5iNjLWLu8u4&id=9&op=do
Referrer    http://drupal220/update.php?op=selection&token=bLDFFBM8NZi09U0is5p6eim_do1vePHV5iNjLWLu8u4&op=start&id=9
Message Notice: Undefined index: label in uuid_update_7103() (line 266 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal220\sites\all\modules\uuid\uuid.install).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems is an error from the uuid module, try to downgrade the version to `7.x-1.0-alpha5` and I think it fixes the error.

You can download this version [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2040551).

Comment: Thank you Mario! I downgraded to UUID 7.x-1.0-alpha5 and I didn't get the error when running update. I don't understand why Drupal does not list this release on the main UUID page?

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. This module does not have updates since September 2014...